# Extracting an instagram user's following count and bio

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api, instaloader

I tried everyway including instaloader etc. But everytime I got a problem. How can I extract an user's general information? I tried to use instagram API but API only works on consumer accounts. I tried instaloader it worked but after while I got problems about redirect login http errors etc. I saw profile counter or bio checker on the internet how can they do it? What is the easiest way? Please help me.

Comment: Try web scrapping with something like selenium https://jira.vueling.com/projects/DMA/summary

Comment: Yes I could do that but after while I got http 429 too many requests error. Therefore I'm looking for another way.

Comment: Use an ip proxy and make requests with different ips, here you have some to try it https://geonode.com/free-proxy-list

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. But I've still problems. Now I cannot implement these proxies to selenium. Or the proxies are not working

Comment: The given proxies list is free, so check before doing anything that you have a connection in a given moment if don't change IP's until you found a working proxy.